# Access modal that is in another component in vuejs

Tags: vue.js, modal-dialog, bootstrap-vue

I'm starting to work with vuejs. I have downloaded a template to start the development of a system; everything was right until I wanted to use a modal. It is in a component called baseLayout.vue and I tried to use it in a method in another component. Is it possible that I can manipulate it from another component? I want to open it, update the body with other elements. A fragment of my code is given below:

baseLayout.vue

```
<template>
<b-modal id="modal1" ref="modal1" title="Bootstrap-Vue">
    <p class="my-4">Hello from modal!</p>
</b-modal></template>
```

I tried to use it from here Analytics.vue

```
<template>
<button class="btn-pill btn-shadow btn-wide fsize-1 btn btn-danger btn-lg" v-on:click="showModal()">ShowModal</button></template>
```

In the scripts:

```
methods: {
  showModal(){
    this.$refs.modal1.show()
  }
}
```

I can not find a way to manipulate the modal that is in the component. And I have to use it from there because if I put it in the current component, it is superimposed by the header and other elements.

Comment: Do you essentially want to pass event from one component to another that's not its direct parent? There are several ways to do it. Alternatively, you can just emit events on `$root` as described [here](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/modal/#emitting-events-on-root)

Comment: Thank you very much, I already managed to open it, now as I do to acatilzar the elements that it has in the body.

Comment: Just an unrelated suggestion: if you are new to Vue could be helpful to use @vue/cli instead of templates.

Answer (score 3):

I faced pretty the same problem.

1. You can pass `modalShow` field as a prop to the `BaseLayout.vue`
   component and modify modal as 
   `<b-modal v-model="modalShow">...</b-modal>` 
   ([BootstarpPropExample](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/modal/#using-v-model-property)). 
   But I found this way pretty complicated if modal window in a separate component. 
   That's because you have to pass, emit and process modalShow variable state across all 
   levels.

***IMHO the second way is more laconic and fancier***

2. In `BaseLayout.vue` add `show()` method:

   ```
   <template>
       <b-modal id="modal1" ref="modal1" title="Bootstrap-Vue">
           <p class="my-4">Hello from modal!</p>
       </b-modal>
   </template>

   <script>
       export default {
           methods: {
               show() {
                   this.$refs.modal1.show();
               }
           }
       }
   </script>
   ```

   And in `Analytics.vue` import modal component and insert it into the
   template with a preferable ref name, so you can also call his methods with
   $refs:

   ```
   <template>
       <div>
           <button class="btn-pill btn-shadow btn-wide btn btn-danger btn-lg" @click="showModal()">
               ShowModal
           </button>
           <BaseLayout ref="modalComponent"/>
       </div>
   </template>

   <script>
       import BaseLayout from "./BaseLayout";

       export default {
           components: {
               BaseLayout
           },
           methods: {
               showModal() {
                   this.$refs.modalComponent.show();
               }
           }
       }
   </script>
   ```